# AOSP build base_rules.mk already defined error

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build the android source code in OS X 10.12.5, but I got an error. Now I want your help to build the android source code.My java version is 'java version "1.8.0_31"'.
when I run make it hava some error

```
 [38/38] bootstrap out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
 [1/2] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/minibp out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
 [4/4] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/minibp out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
 [496/497] glob test/vts/utils/native/trace_processor/Android.bp
 [46/46] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
 out/build-aosp_arm.ninja is missing, regenerating...
 Checking build tools versions...
 [2/691] including ./art/Android.mk ...
 art/build/Android.common.mk:50: warning: unsupported HOST_ARCH=x86_64
 [9/691] including ./cts/Android.mk ...
 cts/tests/tests/telecom3/Android.mk:37: warning: FindEmulator: find: `cts/tests/tests/telecom/src/android/telecom/cts/MockDialerActivity.java': No such file or directory
 [187/691] including ./external/googletest/Android.mk ...
 build/core/base_rules.mk:238: error: external/googletest/googletest: MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.libgtest already defined by external/googletest/googletest.
 16:57:43 ckati failed with: exit status 1
 make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1

 #### make failed to build some targets (01:23 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Comment: what is android version?

Comment: thanks you ,I soved this by `repo init -b android-7.1.1_r11
repo sync` then build

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
unset NDK_ROOT
```

I found it in:

> 3, build/core/base_rules.mk:238: error: external/googletest/googletest: MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.libgtest already defined by external/googletest/googletest. 16:57:43 ckati failed with: exit status 1 is compiling In the process encountered this problem many times, the problem is that something is redefined, and later multiple search, the original is that I set the NDK_ROOT and SDK_ROOT in the mac environment variable, which is the path of the NDK and SDK, and then compiled later Android source code will conflict with them, so temporarily cancel the set of NDK and SDK environment variables, you can solve this problem.

[translated by 'google translate' from here](https://blog.csdn.net/suningning/article/details/77552962)